# Why doesn't the orange light filter appear bluish if it transmitts orange and reflects or absorbs all other frequencies?

Tags: optics, visible-light

I was going through the absorption and reflection phenomenon of light and this question struck my mind as I was walking through the light filters. Why does orange filter not appear bluish if it transmitts orange light and reflects all other lights except orange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually two major types of filters:

1. Absorption filter

A piece of orange glass (like in a photo camera filter), for example, is an absorption filter. It absorbs higher frequency light, and doesn't absorb much the red-orange frequencies. The result is that due to the usual, [Snell's reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law) these are reflected, but due to transparency of the glass they are also transmitted.

Here's an example of a photographic absorption filter:

[image: example of absorption filter]

([image source](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/54197-REG/Tiffen_77OR21_77mm_Orange_21_Glass.html))

2. Reflection/scattering filter

Some kinds of opalescent glass, on the other hand, look orange when you look at a white light *through* a sample, but when viewed from the side, it's blue. This is exactly what you expect. Same result will be with an [interference filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_filter), which, instead of scattering the unwanted wavelengths, specularly reflects them.

Here's an example of the opalescent glass:

[image: example of a piece of opalescent glass]

([image source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Why_is_the_sky_blue.jpg))

Comment: There's a nice photo of some interference filters (including an orange one) at the top of this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichroic_filter

Comment: Thanks for your answer